# Adding an element of a sub-vector-space with an element of the parent vector-space yields an element of the sub-vector-space. Meaning of this?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Please consider a vector-space $V$ (over field $F$), and a set $W$ which is a sub-vector-space of $V$.

Consider some vector $x$ which is in $W$, and a vector $y$ which is in $V$ but not necessarily in $W$.

Suppose we know that $(x + y)$ resides in $W$.

Does that necessarily mean that $y$ is in $W$? Why or why not?

Comment: can you give me an equation for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $(x+y)$? So $y=…$?

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition**. Let $V$ be a vector space and $W \subset V$ a sub-vector space of $V$. Given $x,y \in V$, suppose $x+y \in W \subset V$ and $x \in W$ **then** $y \in W$.

*Proof.*

Since $x \in W$ sub-vector space, there is $-x \in W$ such that $-x + x = 0$, also $-x + (x + y) \in W$ (since $W$ is closed under addition), then $-x + (x + y) \in W \iff 0 + y \in W$, the zero vector $0$ of $W$, must be the same as $V$, then $0 + y \in W \iff y \in W$.